# Discord.py get my actual avatar url and name

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Im am right now creating an info command for my discord bot and want to make a footer in an embed with the developers/my name and avatar.
But now if I add my name and avatar url to the field then when I change name or avatar the informations in the footer will still stay the same.

Is there something I can use, to get my own avatr url and name just like I get the ctx.author.avatar_url and ctx.author?

Or is threre something like bot.owner?

This is my code:

```
user_me = ?

em = discord.Embed()
em.set_footer(icon_url=user_me.avatar_url, text=user_me)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried to define for example `owner` with your ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use your id, and from that you can create a user object.

```py
user = await bot.fetch_user(<your_id>)
em = discord.Embed()
em.set_footer(icon_url=user.avatar_url, text=user.name)
```

Comment: @PaulWeinmann make sure to mark my answer as correct by clicking the check button below the downvote button next to my post!